# How to resign SWRevealViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController to implement sidebar in my IOS app.I have followed appcoda tutorial to implement it, I need to resign the sidebar to orignal position in a tableview row click can anyone help with the answer.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
if ( revealViewController )
{
//        [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
//        [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just toggle the easiest way is to call this in the `viewcontroller` with your tableview

`[self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];`

Don't forget to put this import

`import <SWRevealViewController/SWRevealViewController.h>`